# Why is only one of the given statements about complexity classes correct?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Apparently the correct answer to the following question is (C), but why are the other options not correct until we know the value of n?

If n=1, all of these seem correct except (B)! Where am I going wrong?

> Which of the following is not O(n<sup>2</sup>)?
>
> (A) 15<sup>10</sup> * n + 12099
>   
>   (B) n<sup>1.98</sup>
>   
>   (C) n<sup>3</sup> / √n
>   
>   (D) 2<sup>20</sup> * n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) says :-

> Big O
>   notation describes the limiting behavior of a function when the
>   argument tends towards a particular value or infinity, usually in
>   terms of simpler functions. A description of a function in terms of big O notation usually only
>   provides an ***upper bound*** on the growth rate of the function.

An upper bound means that f(n) = n can be expressed as O(n), O(n<sup>2</sup>), O(n<sup>3</sup>), and others but not in other functions like O(1), O(log n).

So, going in the same direction, now you can easily eliminate options as shown below :-

1. 15<sup>10</sup> * n + 12099 < c * n<sup>2</sup>, for some n > √12100 i.e. n > 110 --- hence is O(n<sup>2</sup>).
2. n<sup>1.98</sup> < n<sup>2</sup>, for all n > 1 --- and is O(n<sup>2</sup>).
3. n<sup>3</sup> / √n = n<sup>5/2</sup> > n<sup>2</sup> for all n > 1 --- hence, isn't O(n<sup>2</sup>).
4. 2<sup>20</sup> * n = 1024*1024*n < c* n<sup>2</sup> for all n > 1 ,where c = 1024*1024 --- hence, is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Hence, the only option which doesn't satisfy O(n<sup>2</sup>) is option C,i.e., ***`f(n) = (n^3 / (sqrt(n)))`***. Here, so, ***(n<sup>3</sup> / (sqrt(n))) isn't equal to O(n<sup>2</sup>)***.

Comment: O(n^2) is a set, so it is better to say n^2.5 *isn't in* O(n^2). (And formatting comments is a pain.)

Comment: @rici-Actually, that was for OP to clearly understand my statement. But, improved that as per the definition. THANKS... :)

Comment: @shekharsuman , does big o notation mean "atleast" this order for f(n)=n O(n),O(n^2),O(n^3) all are true, but we formally accept O(n) so it must be f(n) has atleast O(n)? right?

Comment: @big O notation provides an upper bound for the growth rate of the function. So, obviously,*in your words*, **the function must be at least some-order such that function<=some-order**, AND higher-orders are all permissible. I hope this clears your doubt. Good luck, :)

Comment: @shekharsuman: Why do you say, in case 4, “2²⁰*n = {(1/10)^n}”? When n = 1, 2²⁰* ≠ 1/10! But since n > 1 ⇒ 2²⁰*n < 2²⁰*n² we see that 2²⁰*n _is_ O(n²).

Comment: @PJTraill-That's my misjudgement, I overlooked the last question as (2/20)^n. I apologise for the same. I am making the necessary edit.

Answer (score 0):

While Shekhar Suman’s answer explains why the official answer is right in each case, it does not answer this part of the question: *“Apparently the correct answer to the following question is (C), but why are the other options not correct **until we know the value** of n? **If n = 1**, all of these seem correct except (B)! **Where am I going wrong**?”* (my highlighting).

I would suggest that the first two parts I have put in bold indicate what the questioner – at the time of asking – had not grasped, namely that O-notation is used to express information about functions, not about particular values of expressions.

This means it makes no sense to say “**If n = 1, f(n) is O(n<sup>2</sup>)**”, as that is a statement about one value, f(1), and not about the function f.

Similarly, “**until we know the value of n**” makes no sense when talking about functions, because **n** is a *bound variable*, i.e. is only used to relate **n** to an expression involving **n** in order to define a function.

Answer (score -1):

None of the options are of order n^2.

(15^10) * n + 12099 is of order n

n^1.98 is of order n^1.98

n^3 / (sqrt(n)) is of order n^2.5

(2^20) * n is of order n

You can check whether two functions are of the same order, by dividing one over the other. It should tend to go to a constant when n goes to infinity.

Comment: n^1.98/n^2 goes to 0 as n goes to infinity, and 0 is certainly a constant. Ditto for options A and D.

Comment: big-O is an *upper* bound, so the answer of the OP is correct.